# OpenTK GL.Translate 2D camera on GLControl

Tags: c#, opengl, camera, opentk

I am doing some ascii game, via using OpenTK & Winforms. And stack with Camera movement and view in 2D.

Those code i am using for mouse event and translate positions:

```
    public static Point convertScreenToWorldCoords(int x, int y)
    {
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        Matrix4 modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
        GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ModelviewMatrix, out modelViewMatrix);
        GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ProjectionMatrix, out projectionMatrix);
        GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Viewport, viewport);
        Vector2 mouse;
        mouse.X = x;
        mouse.Y = y;
        Vector4 vector = UnProject(ref projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, new Size(viewport[2], viewport[3]), mouse);
        Point coords = new Point((int)vector.X, (int)vector.Y);
        return coords;
    }

    public static Vector4 UnProject(ref Matrix4 projection, Matrix4 view, Size viewport, Vector2 mouse)
    {
        Vector4 vec;

        vec.X = 2.0f * mouse.X / (float)viewport.Width - 1;
        vec.Y = 2.0f * mouse.Y / (float)viewport.Height - 1;
        vec.Z = 0;
        vec.W = 1.0f;

        Matrix4 viewInv = Matrix4.Invert(view);
        Matrix4 projInv = Matrix4.Invert(projection);

        Vector4.Transform(ref vec, ref projInv, out vec);
        Vector4.Transform(ref vec, ref viewInv, out vec);

        if (vec.W > float.Epsilon || vec.W < float.Epsilon)
        {
            vec.X /= vec.W;
            vec.Y /= vec.W;
            vec.Z /= vec.W;
        }

        return vec;
    }

    //on mouse click event
    Control control = sender as Control;
    Point worldCoords = convertScreenToWorldCoords(e.X, control.ClientRectangle.Height - e.Y);
    playerX = (int)Math.Floor((double)worldCoords.X / 9d);
    playerY = (int)Math.Floor((double)worldCoords.Y / 9d);
```

And those code will setup my Projection, but, something wrong here...

```
    //Set Projection
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Ortho(0, Width * charWidth * scale, Height * charHeight * scale, 0, -1, 1);
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Translate(playerX, playerY, 0);
```

Well, my problem is GL.Translate. In this case, they not focused on playerX,Y and movement of "camera" seems reversed. If i am put GL.Translate(-playerX, -playerY, 0); - They seems moves correct, but anyways View seems not focused on player Object (player object should be always on center position of view, typical top-down view camera). But I dont know how to setting up them correctly. My experiments, multiple, devide, etc. with my X,Y pos - does not give me correct view. How it should be in this case?

Comment: It appears to me that you are complicating matters for no apparent reason. Set up orthogonal projection matrix (I prefer one where 1pixel is 1 unit) and you're good to go. Keep it simple.